# How is this even possible? PHP memory error -- allowed memory size / bytes exhausted

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, php5, outofmemoryerror

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1540673 bytes) in /home/appdev/glicious/Nutrition.php on line 41`

If you haven't noticed, 134217728 is two orders of magnitude greater than 1540673.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first number is the maximum amount you can allocate, the second is the amount you attempted to allocate that bumped you over the edge. You could have had (first number - 1) bytes allocated already...